# Convert IST to UK time

Tags: php, timezone

How to convert time string in minute and seconds to UK time:-

```
<?php 
     $time='9:00';
     $dt = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
     foreach($users as user)
     {
      $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
      echo $user.$dt->format('H:i') . PHP_EOL;  
     }
?>
```

Not getting result when i loop it

please help

Comment: what is issue `3.30` to `9:00` difference is `5:30`. IST = UTC+5:30 hours so UTC is 5.30 Hour behind IST

Comment: Sorry to mention the issue, the issue is when i iterate this in for loop am not getting the result

Comment: Make sure you recognize that London is not the same as UTC - as London has +1 hour for daylight saving time during the summer (aka BST - British Summer Time).

Comment: Also, your question doesn't show the for loop you mention.  Your code should be able to reproduce the problem you describe.  Please edit. Thanks.